This does not look like a tar archive, A lone zero block a at 24
I performed this
C:\Users\User> adb exec-out "cd /storage/sdcard1 && tar c * -" > extsdcard.tar

The file returned this:
User@LAPTOP-DJH6CVKH MINGW64 /a/realme 5/sdcard
$ file extsdcard.tar
extsdcard.tar: data

I tried this:
$ tar -tf extsdcard.tar
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: A lone zero block at 24
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Here is the size of file:
User@LAPTOP-DJH6CVKH MINGW64 /a/realme 5/sdcard
$ ls -alh
total 23G
drwxr-xr-x 1 User 197609   0 May 19 12:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 User 197609   0 May 19 07:27 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197609 23G May 19 12:40 extsdcard.tar

Tell me if there is something missing info.

I don't know what version of tar Android comes with, but the command line seems wrong. There is an extra - character at the end. I guess it is meant to specify standard out, but there is no corresponding f option. The - is superfluous because the output goes to standard out by default, but if you want to specify it, the command line should look like this: tar cf - *.

@JohanMyréen Some implementations of tar default to writing to a tape drive device when used without the -f option. GNU tar might write to standard output by default, but check with tar --show-defaults before assuming that (it's a compile-time setting).

@Kusalananda, GNU tar will also honour the $TAPE environment variable; even with a GNU tar compiled to default to stdout, I would still use f - to make sure it goes to stdout. BTW, should be tar cf - ./*, or tar cf - -- *, not tar cf - * unless you can guarantee none of the filenames start with -.
